# Trying to replace a HTML text when the select option is changed, with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class which content I need to replace through HTML `select` and `option`. Oddly the `jQuery` code to replace the content only works in first try. It won't work if I try to choose different `option`.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#selectTable1 .charts-provinsi").on('change', function(e) {
  var tableName = $('#selectTable1 .charts-provinsi').find(":selected").text();

  $("#sourceTable1 .table-name").replaceWith(tableName);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectTable1">
  <p><em>Table 1</em></p>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="charts-provinsi form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Pilih Daerah">
                    <option class="lvl1" value="1" name="SG" selected="selected">Singapore</option>
                    <option class="lvl1" value="2" name="ID">Indonesia</option>
                    <option class="lvl2" value="3" name="MY">Malaysia</option>
                    <option class="lvl1" value="4" name="PH">Philippines</option>
                  </select>
  </div>



  <div id="sourceTable1">
    <h4 class="h4 table-title">
      <strong>Table 1</strong> <span class="table-name">Singapore</span>
    </h4>

    <table id="dataTable" class="table dataTable">
      <tr class="year">
        <td></td>
        <th>2010</th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
        <th>2015</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 1</th>
        <td>40355</td>
        <td>39544</td>
        <td>30280</td>
        <td>37123</td>
        <td>39129</td>
        <td>41234</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 2</th>
        <td>32760</td>
        <td>37700</td>
        <td>39000</td>
        <td>35023</td>
        <td>39234</td>
        <td>37230</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 3</th>
        <td>37326</td>
        <td>37386</td>
        <td>38000</td>
        <td>37504</td>
        <td>38120</td>
        <td>39102</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `replaceWith`, it is replacing the actual element, so the first time it works, but the next time it cannot find it because it was replaced. You want to replace the content of the element, not the element itself. Change `replaceWith` to `html` and it will work:

```js
$("#selectTable1 .charts-provinsi").on('change', function(e) {
  var tableName = $('#selectTable1 .charts-provinsi').find(":selected").text();

  $("#sourceTable1 .table-name").html(tableName);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectTable1">
  <p><em>Table 1</em></p>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="charts-provinsi form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Pilih Daerah">
                    <option class="lvl1" value="1" name="SG" selected="selected">Singapore</option>
                    <option class="lvl1" value="2" name="ID">Indonesia</option>
                    <option class="lvl2" value="3" name="MY">Malaysia</option>
                    <option class="lvl1" value="4" name="PH">Philippines</option>
                  </select>
  </div>



  <div id="sourceTable1">
    <h4 class="h4 table-title">
      <strong>Table 1</strong> <span class="table-name">Singapore</span>
    </h4>

    <table id="dataTable" class="table dataTable">
      <tr class="year">
        <td></td>
        <th>2010</th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
        <th>2015</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row1">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 1</th>
        <td>40355</td>
        <td>39544</td>
        <td>30280</td>
        <td>37123</td>
        <td>39129</td>
        <td>41234</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 2</th>
        <td>32760</td>
        <td>37700</td>
        <td>39000</td>
        <td>35023</td>
        <td>39234</td>
        <td>37230</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3">
        <th class="row-title">
          <a href="#" title="Hapus data" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove fa-lg row-delete"></a> (SG) Row 3</th>
        <td>37326</td>
        <td>37386</td>
        <td>38000</td>
        <td>37504</td>
        <td>38120</td>
        <td>39102</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It's weird though. What's the difference between `.replaceWith()` and `.html()`? Why does the former only works once and the latter always works?

Comment: `text()` will work too. Both `text()` and `html()` replace the content. `html()` replaces the entire HTML content, while `text()` only replaces the text between the HTML tags. In your case, there are no HTML tags and all you have inside is text, so both `text()` and `html()` will do the same. However, you didn't use `text()` in your question, you used `replaceWith()` which is the problem.